# VBA Label Property is showing FALSE at the end of code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to update Label Caption property as a part of progress of code being executed to let user know what task is being performed. Everything works great until code is completed. In the end it is showing **FALSE** value instead of retailing all the message what was shown. How do I make sure it keeps all the message which was shown ? `Forms!Main!Message.Caption = Forms!Main!Message.Caption` is the one showing progress of message to the Label Control.

Here is sample code:

```vb
If strSource_System <> "" Then

    '--Download AP Data
    Forms!Main!.ctrlProgressBar.Value = Timer - startTime
    Forms!Main!Message.Caption = Forms!Main!Message.Caption & vbCrLf & "Downloading AP Data for System " & strSource_System & ". Please be patient..."
    SleepSec (1)
    Forms!Main!.ctrlProgressBar.Value = Timer - startTime
        Call Download_AP_Data(Source_CONNECTION, "SOURCE")
    Forms!Main!.ctrlProgressBar.Value = Timer - startTime
    'Reset Clock
    startTime = Timer
    Forms!Main!Message.Caption = Forms!Main!Message.Caption & vbCrLf & "AP Data Downloaded for System " & strSource_System & " Successfully."
    SleepSec (1)
    Forms!Main!.ctrlProgressBar.Value = Timer - startTime

End If
```

Comment: I do not see how this code can possibly set the Message label to "FALSE". Btw., if this code is in the `Main` Form, then you don't need the `Forms!Main!` part. You can simply write `ctrlProgressBar.Value = Timer - startTime` or `Message.Caption = Message.Caption & "whatever"`. I also would call `DoEvents` after changing the message to make it display the change instantly.

Comment: Thank you for response. This Module is outside of Main form. Message.Caption = Message.Caption & "whatever" is working until code is being executed but at the end it is  showing me FALSE only value and removing all previous text. not sure why. ctrlProgressBar is seperate control outside of label which is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending all messages to the same label. The label's text might exceed its maximum length at some point and produce an error. If you have an `On Error Resume Next`, you will not see this error.

I suggest using a `ListBox` instead. This allows you to add the messages as new items into the `ListBox`. The Row Source Type of the ListBox must be `Value List`.

A Label can hold a maximum of 2,048 characters. A ListBox in ValueList mode can hold up to 64K characters (i.e., 32 times more).

If this is not enough, bind the ListBox to a table and add up to 64 records (i.e., up to 64k messages).

But you could also limit the number of messages displayed and start deleting the first messages when exceeding this limit to get a rolling display.

```vb
messageListBox.AddItem "Downloading AP Data for System " & strSource_System & ". Please be patient..."
DoEvents
```

And if you automatically want to scroll to the last item added, you can do this

```vb
' Scroll to the last item
messageListBox.SetFocus 'Next line does not work otherwise.
messageListBox.ListIndex = messageListBox.ListCount - 1

' Unselect it
messageListBox.Selected(messageListBox.ListCount - 1) = False
```

It's easier to extract this code to another Sub

```vb
Private Sub DisplayMessage(ByVal message As String)
    messageListBox.AddItem message
    messageListBox.SetFocus
    messageListBox.ListIndex = messageListBox.ListCount - 1
    messageListBox.Selected(messageListBox.ListCount - 1) = False
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

and then call it with

```vb
DisplayMessage "some message"
```

If you make this Sub public, then you can even place it in the Main form and then call it from the module with

```vb
Forms!Main.DisplayMessage "some message"
```

This has the advantage that this module does not have to know anything about a label or ListBox. The same could be done with a Sub `ShowProgress`.

Comment: On Error Resume Next did not fix issue in my label control. I am not able to make it work unbound Listbox control using sample code you have provided. What am I doing wrong. No text is showing in controlbox at all. I am not using any table to store date.

Comment: I forgot to say that you must set the Row Source Type of the ListBox to **Value List** (since it is not bound to a table or query).